# MooTools version of jQuery's namedspace events?

Tags: jquery, namespaces, mootools, mootools-events

jQuery lets you do things like

```
$div.bind('click.namespace', function)
$div.unbind('click.namespace')
```

Is there any equivalent in MooTools? I tried defining a [pseudo event](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Event.Pseudos):

```
Event.definePseudo('shim', function(split, fn, args) {fn.apply(this, args);})

document.body.addEvent('click', function(){alert('regular click');});
document.body.addEvent('click:shim', function(){alert('shim click');});

document.body.removeEvents('click') // removes both!
document.body.removeEvents('click:shim') // removes neither!
```

That seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented it using Element.implement, but my question is asking for a native MooTools way to do it, without defining my own functions.

```
Element.implement({
    // Call as element.bind('event.namespace', function() {});
    bind: function(name, funktion) {
        // Get event type and namespace
        var split = name.split('.'),
            eventName = split[0],
            namespace = split[1];

        // Store the event by its full name including namespace
        this.bindCache = this.bindCache || {};

        if(this.bindCache[name]) {
            this.bindCache[name].push(funktion);
        } else {
            this.bindCache[name] = [funktion];
        }

        // Bind the function to the event
        this.addEvent(eventName, funktion);
    },

    // Call as element.unbind('event.namespace');
    unbind: function(name) {
        // Unbind the specified event
        var eventName = name.split('.')[0],
            funktions = this.bindCache[name],
            x = 0,
            funktion;

        for(; funktion = funktions[x++]; ) {
            this.removeEvent(eventName, funktion);
        }
    }
});

document.body.bind('click.1', function() {alert('click 1');});
document.body.bind('click.1', function() {alert('click 1 other');});
document.body.bind('click.2', function() {alert('click 2');});

document.body.unbind('click.1'); // leaves click.2
```